# Why I need to reload my CSS to display it properly ?

Tags: css

I have built a stylesheet but it doesn't appears on the page on the first load. It needs a reload to appear properly. However when I look to the source download on the dev console's network tab, I see the CSS is well downloaded. So what can lead to the non-display of my CSS  on the first load since it is well loaded in a CSS module-hash's mode ?

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: I guess it related to browser cache. I found some interesting article here https://www.fastly.com/blog/clearing-cache-browser

Comment: thanks, more precisely  my CSS is displayed broken on the first load, then I reload it, then it breaks anew, etc. So it woul me the cache save a break version of my CSS each time I launch it  ?